# Angular - Data Binding with ngFor directive

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular2-databinding

I am new to angular and I'm not sure of how to render data as HTML markup. How can I show the component data inside of the component template?

There is a small reproduction in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SzOc9GfgzvCBb7Fifvg?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

```or-tag-here
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ul class= "master">
                <li *ngFor ="let student of liArraycontent">  </li>
              </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
  liArraycontent = ["testing 1", "testing 2", "testing3"]


}
```

Answer (score 2):

So inside of your code for the list just do this:

```
<li *ngFor ="let student of liArraycontent">{{student}}</li>
```

And similarly if you had an array of objects you could just do `{{student.name}}` or any other attributes for the object

Answer (score 1):

To show information from your data source (component class) in your template (html code) you need to use ***interpolation***. You can do this by using the double curly brace syntax `{{}}` inside of your template. By doing that, you will automatically bind the data in one direction: data source to template. That means, if the data changes in the data source, the changes will be reflected in your template.

I would recommend u to read the following section of the docs:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Hope it helps!